# Published Report behaves differently than Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have the below tab in a report that contains 5 visualizations and a table.   Filtering between them works just fine in Desktop.

[image: How the tab looks/works in Power BI Desktop]

After publishing the report to the Power BI service, it looks like this. Refreshing has no effect.

[image: Same tab on Power BI service]

I have tried duplicating the tab and also re-created it completly and the same occurs.

Any suggestions to resolve this is appreciated.   BTY, all the other tabs in the report work perfectly after publishing.    It is just this one that is problematic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe some higher power is telling you not to use donut charts .... I would support that. That aside, have you checked if there are any context filters?

Comment: I changed the donuts to pie charts and result is the same.   Online, there are no filters set other than those for each of the charts.

Comment: That was a joke. Pie charts and donut charts are not good data visualisations, but that will not be the reason for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the cause and it may be a bug.

The visualizations on the tab rely on a filtered field name MailboxExistsFlag, which is either true or false.  In Desktop, the filters look like this:

[image: Filter on Desktop]

When the pbix file is published, the same filters translate to this, which is different:

[image: Filter after publishing]

To resolve, I edited each filter in the online version and selected "-1" in lieu of TRUE.   After doing so, all the visualizations work as they should.   I expect I will have to do this to the page if I make changes to the report and publish again.

Why TRUE/FALSE becomes -1/0 in online escapes me, but beware if you have reports that have such columns.

Comment: Changing the type of the flag column in Power Query to True/False will resolve this issue.